# Json Filtering in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, json

Hello i want to filter json data like sql query without the help of plugins like alasql.js or linq.js or any plugins.
for example

```
{
    "Managing PCL": [
        {
            "idItScreen": "1436",
            "topicName": "Managing PCL",
            "isFav": 0,
            "cdeItScreen": "ListActiveTarif",
            "busScreenName": "My Current Tarif"
        },
        {
            "idItScreen": "1437",
            "topicName": "Managing PCL",
            "isFav": 0,
            "cdeItScreen": "ListTermineTarif",
            "busScreenName": "History Tarif"
        }
    ]
}
```

for example i need to get data where idItScreen>1430 so that json data must be displayed the main challenge is to do without plugins so please reccomend me a good solution to do this without plugins

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/    <--- this may help

Answer (score 1):

First turn your JSON into a Javascript object:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
```

Then do your filtering:

```
var matches = [];
var arr = obj['Managing PCL'];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].idItScreen > 1430) {
        matches.push(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Or using [jQuery.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/):

```
var matches = jQuery.grep(obj['Managing PCL'], function(n, i) {
    return n.idItScreen > 1430;
});
```

Now `matches` contains the matching items.

If you want to get the JSON again, just use `JSON.stringify`:

```
var filteredJSON = JSON.stringify({'Managing PCL': matches});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply use `.filter`:

```
var matches = [];
var all = obj['Managing PCL'];
var filtered = all.filter(function(){
  return $(this).idItScreen > 1430;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this. Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the data instead.

```
function filterData(data, key, value) {
  return data.filter(function (el) {
      return el[key] > value;
  });
}

// Note, `filter` operates on arrays, so you need to specify the
// array that contains the data
var result = filterData(data['Managing PCL'], 'idItScreen', '1430');
```

Also note that `filter` returns a new array containing the objects that it's found that match your criteria. You can access those objects in the usual way: `result[0]`, for example.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6j9sbsft/)

You could even expand this to create a function that returns data based on the operator too, not just greater-than, by using a look-up object:

```
var lookup = {
    '>': function (data, value) { return data > value; },
    '<': function (data, value) { return data < value; },
    '===': function (data, value) { return data === value; }
}

function filterData(data, key, operator, value) {
    return data.filter(function (el) {
        return lookup[operator](el[key], value);
    });
}

filterData(data['Managing PCL'], 'idItScreen', '>', '1430');
filterData(data['Managing PCL'], 'idItScreen', '===', '1430');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ftgw75ht/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use jQuery for this. You can use the `filter()` method of `Array.prototype`. See the working snippet below:

```js
var obj = {
  "Managing PCL": [{
    "idItScreen": "1436",
    "topicName": "Managing PCL",
    "isFav": 0,
    "cdeItScreen": "ListActiveTarif",
    "busScreenName": "My Current Tarif"
  }, {
    "idItScreen": "1437",
    "topicName": "Managing PCL",
    "isFav": 0,
    "cdeItScreen": "ListTermineTarif",
    "busScreenName": "History Tarif"
  }]
};

var filteredArray = obj['Managing PCL'].filter(function(item) {
  return item.idItScreen > 1430;
});

obj['Managing PCL'] = filteredArray;
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```